# React native nat find file ~/.profile

Tags: react-native

I want to create android project but I stuck at the setup step 4

[image]

I don't know where `~/.profile` is.

Can you guys tell me where is that file ?

Comment: `~` is your user folder in */Users/* folder. Do `cd ~` and then `pwd` to see where is it exactly

Comment: you using linux, mac or windows?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly I use mac os

Comment: Just install this https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html it will set all environment variables and simulators

Comment: @Cherniv when I type `pwd` I've got this `/Users/MyUserName`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly It's not work. When I try to run `react-native run-android` and it say `SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable`

Comment: First of all you need SDK, then you need to setup environment vars, Android studio has sdk and will automatically set env vars for you

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly But I've already install SDK follow react-native Getting start guide (6.0 Marshmallow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solve!

Finally I found .profile file
It's in ~/etc/.profile

and then copy this code and paste it

`export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk
 export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
 export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools`

That's it.